# Item has already been added. Key in dictionary c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-membership

I am receiving an error in the

```
var passwords
```

The error is Item has already been added.

> Key in dictionary: 'sample@email.com'  Key being added:
> 'sample@email.com'

```
int totalrecords= 2;

if (encrypted == null || hashedProvider == null) 
    return;

var passwords = encrypted
  .GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out dontCare)
  .Cast<MembershipUser>()
  .Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true)
  .ToDictionary(u => u.UserName, u => u.GetPassword());
```

Is there a way resolve this issue?

Comment: There is one or more duplicates of username, how do you want to deal with it? Choose your own adventure

Comment: You can remove duplicates returned by encrypted.GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out totalrecords).Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true).OrderByDescending(u => u.CreationDate)

Comment: @user2250152 Hello Sir. How do I remove the duplicates? Wait let me modify the code.

Comment: @TheGeneral Good Day Sir. I wanted to remove the duplicates or ignore or dont save it in the dictionary if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply group the results and select the first

```
var passwords = encrypted
  .GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out dontCare)
  .Cast<MembershipUser>()
  .Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true)
  .GroupBy(x => x.UserName)
  .ToDictionary(u => u.Key, y => y.First().GetPassword());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Sir. I already tried the code above but I am encountering a connection timeout. I approximately got 200k of data. I already set the connection timeout to 0 in my config but it still showing. I will get back to this once I fix the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried the code above and its still getting the same error in the .GetAllUsers().

Comment: @Key2020 you cant be getting the same error in the same place unless there is code you have not shared in GetAllUsers

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `MemberShupUser.UserName` as key in the Dictionary.

The error message says that you are trying to add a Key that is already in the Dictionary.

Apparently your Usernames are not unique.

To check this before you are creating the Dictionary, make groups of users that have the same UserName, and count the number of UserNames.

```
var usersToAddTodictionary = encrypted
   .GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out totalrecords)           
   .Cast<MembershipUser>();
IEnumerable<string> duplicateUserNames = usersToAddToDictionary

    // make groups of MemberShipUsers that have the same UserName
    .GroupBy(memershipUser => membershipUser.UserName,

        // parameter resultSelector: for every UserName and all MemberShipUsers that have
        // this UserName, make one new:
        (userName, memberShipUsersWithThisUserName) => new
        {
             UserName = userName,
             HasDuplicates = memberShipUsersWithThisUserName.Skip(1).Any(),

        });
```

To detect whether the UserName has duplicates I check if there is more than one. This is just an efficiency that I don't have to enumerate all elements if after the 2nd one I already know that this UserName has duplicates.

Continuing the LINQ: keep only those groups that has duplicates:

```
    .Where(group => group.HasDuplicates);
    .Select(group => group.UserName);
```

So before you make the Dictionary, you could decide what to do with members that have too many passwords.

You could keep just one element, but which password should you keep?

It is better to check if the user is already registered before he is added to your encrypted database.

Comment: Thank you for answering Sir Harald. I already tried the code above but I am encountering a connection timeout. I approximately got 200k of data. I already set the connection timeout to 0 in my config but it still showing. I will get back to this once I fix the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Until now you didn't mention that you retrieve the data from a database. Maybe if will help if you fetch the data "per page": do you really need all data at once?

Comment: Yes I retrieve the data from the database, table aspnet_membership. I was thinking it would be easier to fetch them all at once but since the error was persisting I was thinking maybe I will be doing it by batch. Maybe 10k per execution or by date. Thank you for your guidance